# I want to store a number between 0 and 100 in a variable - should I use an INT or a BYTE and why?

Tags: java, types

I know this is a n00b question but I want to define a variable with a value between `0` and `100` in JAVA. I can use INT or BYTE as data types - but which one would be the best to use. And why?(benefits?)

Comment: you may not want to use int with 0.01 ...

Comment: Sorry guys. Stupid mistake in the question No decimals. And no, this not for homework. Thanks xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `int` or `byte` would work for storing a number in that range.

Which is best depends on what you are aiming to do.

- If you need to store lots of these numbers in an array, then a `byte[]` will take less space than an `int[]` with the same length.
- (Surprisingly) a `byte` variable takes the same amount of space as a `int` ... due to the way that the JVM does the stack frame / object frame layout.
- If you are doing lots of arithmetic, etc using these values, then `int` is more convenient than `byte`.  In Java, arithmetic and bitwise operations automatically promote the operands to `int`, so when you need to assign back to a `byte` you need to use a `(byte)` type-cast.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, neither one is appropriate--if you need to store the decimal part, you want a float.

I'd personally argue that unless you're actually getting into resource-constrained issues (embedded system, big data, etc.) your code will be slightly clearer if you go with int. Good style is about being legible to people, so indicating that you're working with integers might make more sense than prematurely optimizing and thus forcing future maintainers of your code (including yourself) to speculate as to the *true* nature of that variable.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake in the question. There is no decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Use byte datatype to store value between -128 to 127

Answer (score 0):

I think since you have used `0.00` with decimals, this means you want to allow decimals.
The best way to do this is by using a floating point type: `double` or `float`.

However, if you don't need decimals, and the number is always an integer, you can use either `int` or `byte`. Byte can hold anything up to +127 or down to -128, and takes up much less space than an int.

with 32-bit ints on your system, your `byte` would take up 1/4 of the space!
The disadvantages are that you have to be careful when doing arithmetic on bytes - they can overflow, and cause unexpected results if they go out of range.
If you are using basic IO functions, like creating sounds or reading old file formats, byte is invaluable. But watch out for the sign convention: negative has the high-order bit set. However when doing normal numerical calculations, I always use int, since it allows easy extension to larger values if needed, and 32-bit cpus there is minimal speed cost really. Only thing is if you are storing a large quantity of them.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **byte:** The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be *useful for saving memory in large arrays*, where the memory savings actually matters. They *can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code*; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.
>
> **int:** The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, *this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else*. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use long instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you're doing... out of the blue like that I would say use int because it's a standard way to declare an integer. But, if you do something specific that require memory optimization than maybe byte could be better in that case.